# Real examples of guitar technique Wikipedia calls "polyphonic strumming"

Tags: guitar, strumming, flamenco

While reading about unusual guitar techniques, I found this [article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyphonic_strumming) about something called **polyphonic strumming**. I had never heard of it before, and actually the name they use for it sounds a little bit too grandiose to be accurate in my view. I kind of doubt that some people are *strumming* counterpoint on the guitar, though I'll accept that playing multiple parts can be considered polyphonic. Anyways, I'm a bit intrigued because I'm having a difficult time imagining what this would sound like. However, I can't find any specific examples of this technique and I'm wondering if it really exists and if it really deserves its own special terminology.

Does anyone know of (or can anyone provide) examples or further explanation about this obscure technique?

Comment: Google "Michael Hedges" of Windham Hill fame. He could do things with a guitar that would blow you away. Unfortunately, he was killed in a car accident many years ago. He was an incredible talent the world lost way too young.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, as far as I can find, that as you say it is a bit of an overstatement for what it is. I think it is very similar to a typical flamenco style, with the only reference being to a guy quoted as "Amin Toufani". The only guy of a similar name who is a flamenco guitarist, is a guy called Amin Toofani, who is known for his youtube viral video. Other than that, I can't find any other sources. It does contain some of what could be described as polyphonics, but I'm not sure I'd go as far as to describe it as it's own style of strumming. Hope this helps.